# How can i check a base64 string is a file(what type?) or not?

Tags: base64, decode, base32, ctf

I took the Spentalkux challenge on https://2020.ractf.co.uk/.
This is the first time I do a CTF challenge so I went through a solution on https://github.com/W3rni0/RACTF_2020/blob/master/readme.md#spentalkux

When I receive this base64 string :

```
JA2HGSKBJI4DSZ2WGRAS6KZRLJKVEYKFJFAWSOCTNNTFCKZRF5HTGZRXJV2EKQTGJVTXUOLSIMXWI2KYNVEUCNLIKN5HK3RTJBHGIQTCM5RHIVSQGJ3C6MRLJRXXOTJYGM3XORSIJN4FUYTNIU4XAULGONGE6YLJJRAUYODLOZEWWNCNIJWWCMJXOVTEQULCJFFEGWDPK5HFUWSLI5IFOQRVKFWGU5SYJF2VQT3NNUYFGZ2MNF4EU5ZYJBJEGOCUMJWXUN3YGVSUS43QPFYGCWSIKNLWE2RYMNAWQZDKNRUTEV2VNNJDC43WGJSFU3LXLBUFU3CENZEWGQ3MGBDXS4SGLA3GMS3LIJCUEVCCONYSWOLVLEZEKY3VM4ZFEZRQPB2GCSTMJZSFSSTVPBVFAOLLMNSDCTCPK4XWMUKYORRDC43EGNTFGVCHLBDFI6BTKVVGMR2GPA3HKSSHNJSUSQKBIE
```

I don't know how to check if it is a file, but the solver said that it is a gz compressed data file.

Can you help me, please?
[detail here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QRCde.png)

Link to file: https://github.com/W3rni0/RACTF_2020/blob/master/assets/files/Spentalkux.gz

Comment: I find it quite unlikely that a base64 string of that length would only contain upper case characters. Normal base64 looks more like `m9zMTgKc6o3n8Ye9kOhC4r8loBBCwvARYk94bfSj1YeMpSvAvtLrR1FAdjfnrEl` and probably also contains some `+` and `/`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Many filetypes have a header (the first few bytes of the file) with some fixed information by which a file can be identified as a gz, png, pdf, etc.

So every base64 encoded gz file would also start with a certain sequence of base64 characters, by which it can be recognized.

A [gzip-file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gzip) always starts with the two byte sequence 0x1f 0x1b, which in base64 encoding is `H4` plus a third character in the range of `s` to `v`.

The reason is, that every base64 character represents 6 bits of the original bytes, so the two bytes `0x1f 0x1b` are encoded with two base64 characters (12 bits) plus the first 4 bits of the third character.

Based on that, I would say that's no base64 encoded gzip that you show there.

other examples are:

- [png](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics#File_header)

  starts with: `0x89 0x50 0x4e 0x47 0x0d 0x0a 0x1a 0x0a`

  base64 encoded: `iVBORw0KGg...`
- [jpg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG_File_Interchange_Format#File_format_structure)

  starts with: `0xFF 0xD8 0xFF 0xD0`

  base64 encoded: `/9j/4...`
- [gif](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GIF#File_format)

  starts with: `GIF`

  base64 encoded: `R0lG`
- [tif](http://fileformats.archiveteam.org/wiki/TIFF#Identification)

  a) little endian:
  starts with: `0x49 0x49 0x2A 0x00`

  base64 encoded: `SUkqA`

  b) big endian:
  starts with: `0x4D 0x4D 0x00 0x2A`

  base64 encoded: `TU0AK`
- [flv](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_Video)

  starts with `FLV`

  base64 encoded: `RkxW`
- wav/avi/webp and others

  several audio/video/image/graphic -formats are base on [RIFF(Resource Interchange Format)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Interchange_File_Format)
  The common part is that all files start with `RIFF`

  base64 encoded: `UklGR`

  After the `RIFF`header, you'll find the specific format starting in the 4 bytes starting at the 9th byte.
  In the following `_` is used as a placeholder for any character.

  [wav](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAV)
  starts with: `RIFF____WAVE`
  base64 encoded: `UklGR______XQVZF`

  [webp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebP)
  starts with: `RIFF____WEBP`
  base64 encoded: `UklGR______XRUJQ`

  [avi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio_Video_Interleave)
  starts with: `RIFF____AVI` 
  base64 encoded: `UklGR______BVkkg`

---

Regarding the specific example in the question:

in the updated question there's a hint in the attached picture that

the data is first [base32 encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base32) and then base64 encoded.

When we feed an [online base32 decoder](https://emn178.github.io/online-tools/base32_decode.html) with the string given in the question (`JA2HGSKBJI4DSZ2WGRAS...`), we get:

```
H4sIAJ89gV4A/+1ZURaEIAi8SkfQ+1/O3f7MtEBfMgz9rC/diXmIA5hSzun3HNdBbgbtVP2v/2+LowM837wFHKxZbmE9pQfsLOaiLAL8kvIk4MBma17ufHQbIJCXoWNZZKGPWB5QljvXIuXOmm0SgLixJw8HRC8Tbmz7x5eIspypaZHSWbj8cAhdjli2WUkR1sv2dZmwXhZlDnIcCl0GyrFX6fKkBEBTBsq+9uY2Ecug2Rf0xtaJlNdYJuxjP9kcd1LOW/fQXtb1sd3fSTGXFTx3UjfGFx6uJGjeIAAA
```

It starts with `H4s`, so according to what I wrote about how to recognize file types in base64 encoding, it's a base64 encoded gzip file.

This can be saved in a text file and then uploaded on [base64decode.org](https://www.base64decode.org/) where it will be converted into a gzip file. When you download and open that gzip file it contains a file with text like this:

```
00110000 00110000 00110001 00110001 00110000 00110001 00110000 00110000 00100000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00110001 00110000 00110001 00110000 00110001 00100000 ...
```

Conclusion for this case: The original string/file is a gzip file that was first base64 encoded and the base64 encoded part was again encoded with base32.