# Delphi convert base64 string to PNG image

Tags: delphi, base64, png

I receive a json that has a base64 string with a captcha image so that the user can see and type in the captcha content. the problem that I am not able to show this image in a TImage. the following error occurs:

> class EPNGInvalidFileHeader the file being read is not a valid Portable Network Graphics" image because it contains an invalid header.

String base64

```
/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAgGBgcGBQg
HBwcJCQgKDBQNDAsLDBkSEw8UHRofHh0aHBwgJC4nICI
sIxwcKDcpLDAxNDQ0Hyc5PTgyPC4zNDL/2wBDAQkJCQw
LDBgNDRgyIRwhMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyM
jIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjL/wAARCAAyALQDASIAAh
EBAxEB/8QAHwAAAQUBAQEBAQEAAAAAAAAAAAECAw
QFBgcICQoL/8QAtRAAAgEDAwIEAwUFBAQAAAF9AQIDA
AQRBRIhMUEGE1FhByJxFDKBkaEII0KxwRVS0fAkM2Jyggk
KFhcYGRolJicoKSo0NTY3ODk6Q0RFRkdISUpTVFVWV1hZ
WmNkZWZnaGlqc3R1dnd4eXqDhIWGh4iJipKTlJWWl5iZmq
KjpKWmp6ipqrKztLW2t7i5usLDxMXGx8jJytLT1NXW19jZ2u
Hi4+Tl5ufo6erx8vP09fb3+Pn6/8QAHwEAAwEBAQEBAQE
BAQAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcICQoL/8QAtREAAgECBAQDB
AcFBAQAAQJ3AAECAxEEBSExBhJBUQdhcRMiMoEIFEKRo
bHBCSMzUvAVYnLRChYkNOEl8RcYGRomJygpKjU2Nzg5Ok
NERUZHSElKU1RVVldYWVpjZGVmZ2hpanN0dXZ3eHl6goOE
hYaHiImKkpOUlZaXmJmaoqOkpaanqKmqsrO0tba3uLm6ws
PExcbHyMnK0tPU1dbX2Nna4uPk5ebn6Onq8vP09fb3+Pn6
/9oADAMBAAIRAxEAPwD3OiiitiRrGuN8b+Nf+EQ
+w/8AEv8Atf2rzP8Alt5e3bt/2TnO79K7BsnoK8j
+NYIOh5BH
+v8A/adenlFCnXxcKdVXTv8AkznxM3Cm5R3O78O61/wkO
gW2qfZ/s/n7/wB1v37drFeuB6Z6Vec1wfhfxLpnhv4c6TJqE
xVpPO8uNBud8SvnA9Pc8Ve0z4jaDq12lsrz20rnan2hAoY
+mQSPzrorYCqqlR0oPkTa
+SZlGrHlXM9Tp3NQOasPHJ/zzb8qgaOT/nm35VyxsNldzUD
modZ1BNF0ubULmKYwxbdwReeWCjqQOprCsfGmk39pdX
WZreG22h2nUDJbOAACcn5TXbSw9WcOeMbrYxlJJ2ZuOa
gc1gJ460WaKeQySxrEQAHTmQnP3QDnt3x1FR2XjTSdQu
RAGlhdjhfOUAMfqCf1rqWDrpNuD0MXOPc3HNQuax7HxXY
6nqiWFvFc+a5YKxVdpwCexz29K2Hjk/55t
+VOVKdJ2mrMi99iuxqBzVho5P8Anm35VA8cn/PNvyrSNjN3
IHNV3NWHjk/55t
+VQNHJ/wA82/Kto2MmQOagc1O8cn/PNvyqB45P
+ebflW8bGTIHNQManeOT/nm35VA8cn/PNvyrojYyZCTzR
QY5M/6tvyorTQg
+jKD0rE/4THwv/wBDJo//AIHRf/FUjeMfC+P
+Rk0f/wADov8A4qvgPq1f
+R/cz7DmRtL1NeS/G/8A5gX/AG8f
+066d/ir4Kt55YpNcQsjFSUt5XUkHHDKpBHuDg15z8U/Gnh/
xJ/ZP9k6h9o+z
+d5v7mRNu7Zj7yjP3T0r28lwOKp46nOdOSWurTtszmxLUq
LS3/4Ju+APh/p
+t6BbatrTyXUbh0t7YOyLGods5Iwc7tx4OOfeuc
+JPhKz8L6navp+9bS7RisbNu2MpGQCecfMOvvXS
+A/iV4V0jwdZ6dqGotb3MBkDKbeRgcuzAgqp7N
+lcX8QviFp/i27sjZW91HBbI3+vVQxZiM9GPGFHevYwkcxlm
cnNS9nd76K2trdO2qOepTh7BWXvaE3hzWvFt/qosNM1a7l
mnj2ZuJWdYl4JbDEgYxjOM88da7Sfwh4vs4DdWvi24uLtRu
8iTdsJ9BliPzArz3wb420rwz4gkvZbe7kt5LQQkIi7g/wAhJw
WxjKnv0x9K7W8+N2iLbO1npmoSzjG1JgkannnLBmI4z2NV
j6GN9ulhqK5dOi19bk0oLl99u5VvvFkniL4e6xbXsYi1G1MQk
AGA481RnHY54I/xrn/A/hmLxHd3JupXW1ttjPGhwXY5x
+HBrmZvFXnXOszfYtp1LPyiXiPMqyenP3cdutaPhPx9/wAIv
9s/4ln2n7Ts/wCW
+zbt3f7Jz979K7ngK9HDVI4aNpN3SutL2v8AqZ8kpTTmS6r
YW0njCXTLCIQQm6Fsi7i2DkKTknPXJr1CXwfoTad9j
+wRABcCUDEmfXd1z+leKz
+JJ5/ED6taWgjlNz9pWNmLhTu3YOAM810i/FLxPNIscemW
TO5CqqwSEknoAN9RjcFjKkaapu1lrr1CEEr8xB4MdY/Flm7k
KqiQknsPLauiXVNa8W38yaZcfYdPiODIOGPpz1z7DGK8702
71X7aFsrF553jkjWNIWYkMhU4A54BJ/CtPRL/AMWxTSadp
TLbSbyXhlWJCW4B/wBZznjp7fWujFYPmm6qceZJWvstXdk
Rg0rNnZajpuv6Lp1xcw63LdoEPmLKDuAPGVJJwR17Vp
+F55Ljw5bSzSvLKS
+53YsT8x7n2xXHalc/ELT7dm1CaKKMjlXa1JYegHU1Dpd14
+1O2aTT2Dwo204S3QA/QgVxTwkqlD3qkN907fLRFezs9z0
lzUDmuIPhfx3e/wCkz6p5Ej9YvtTJtxx0QbR0zx/OmHwd4z
HXW/8Aycl/wrnjhKK3rRE6fmdmxqBzXHnwj4xHXWf/ACck/
wAKjPw1mH/MR/8AIA/+KrVYfDL4qy
+SbM3Tj1Z1rGq0sixozuwVFGWYnAA9a5g/DmYf8xD/AMgj
/wCKpo+Hzq6l70smfmAiAJH13HFaqlhf
+fv4MzdOH834G0dW07P/AB/2v/f5f8aKzD4FtP8Anpdf9/E
/worTlwn87+4nkpd39x6T/wAKI8L/APP/AKx/3+i/
+N0xvgV4XH/L/q//AH
+i/wDjdepnpULmvjFnWYf8/WfQOnHscTa/CLwUkKRyaS8z
IoUyPdShnOOp2sBk
+wA9qivvgx4Ou/L8m2urLbnP2e5Y7846793T2x1rvIerfhUt
Z/2pjoyuq0vvY
+SLWx57N8G/BrWaQLZ3McigA3C3Lb29yDlefYCrFl8NfBvh
q3n1C5shdRwRtI73qiUKoGSdgXB49ia7VzTpYo54XhmjSSK
RSro6gqwPUEHqKHmeMkuWdWTT31F7ON72PB0k8BXXj/V
pbyG2TQZbVVt/KtnQLJiPlVVcqch
+cevrXUaB8OfAesK2o6ZNd3lskhjKuSihgASPuK3Qjv3rvf8A
hFvD3/QB0v8A8A4/8Kt2mn2lhC0NjaW9rEW3FIYwik
+uAOvA/Ku3EZvzQSoSnFpJfEraadt/MxjQd/fszK1Pw5p2o
eHJNCEZtrFgoC2+FK7WDcZBHUelZ/hvwhp/hT7V9hmuZPt
Ozf57Kcbc4xhR/eNdS0LHuKja1kPdfzrzo4qoqbpc3ut3a7v
+kW6avzW1OE8ZN4Wu7yDTtffyZzH5kM4yCoJxjcOnTvx
WDFbeCfCcb6ja38d9dopMAM6ysGxxgKMD6npXd674N0zX
yrahbI8qrtWVWKuo9MjtyeD61zQ
+EeiRy7zNduufuNKMfouf1r18Li8MqKpzqTS6pbP0OapTqc1
1FHDfDexkuPE4ugp8q1jZmbsCw2gfqfyrv9b8KaRrchmuoC
s5GDNE21j9ex/EVvWOg2+lWotrGGKGIc4XPJ9SepP1qR7S
T
+8v50YrMnWxHtqb5ei9CI0eWPKziLb4faFayB3W4uMdFmk
4/wDHQK30iit4lihjSONRhUQYAH0rRe0k/vL
+dQPaSf3l/Os54qdb
+JK4uS2yKTmoHNXXtJP7y/nUDWkn95fzpxlHuQ0yk5qBjV1
7ST+
8v51A9pJ/eX863jKPcyaZSc1A5q69pJ/eX86ge0k9V/Ot4yj3
MmmUyeaKmNpJn7y/maK15o9yLM9jPSoWoor42J9GxYOr/
hUp6UUUS3BbET1NRRQwQHpTV6miikMdRRRSAieoHoorW
JDIGqBqKK2iZMgeoHooreJlIgeoHooroiZMgeoHooreJkyBqg
eiitomTIT1ooorUg//2Q==
```

conversion function:

```
var
 s : TMemoryStream;
 png : TPngImage;
 bb : TBytes;
begin
  s := TMemoryStream.Create;
  bb := decodebase64(memo1.Text);
  if Length(bb)>0 then
  begin
    s.WriteData(bb,Length(bb));
    s.position:=0;
    png:=TPngImage.Create;
    png.LoadFromStream(s); // The error occurs here
    //objImg.Picture.Assign(png);
    png.Destroy;
  end;
  s.free;
end;
```

According to the string provider, the image is a png, where am I missing? thanks!

Comment: `/9j/4` is the [JPG header in Base64 encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62330081/7329832), that's probably the reason why PNG conversion fails.

Comment: "_According to the string provider_" - tell him he's wrong and you lost his trust in him. You also could have saved your Base64 decoded bytes to a file which you could have loaded with your favorite picture software to check what that would report.

Comment: For reference, you could have debugged this yourself with a basic understanding of the file formats. Base64 is a binary file encoded as text. You've already managed to decode that Base64 text to an array of bytes. The program tells you that the file is not a png file, so what can it be? Look at the first bytes in your decoded array and compare with the known header bytes for well known image formats.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It decodes to the jpg image shown below. So as mentioned in the comments it is not a PNG image.

[image]