# How get file extension from base64 string

Tags: python, file, base64, byte

How can i get file **extension** from **base64 string**?
OR
How can i get file **extension** from **bytes object**?

```
def get_extension_from_base(base):
    decode_base = base.encode('ascii')
    decode_base = base64.b64decode(decode_base)

    extension =  SOMETHING_HEAR(decode_base)
    
    return extension
```

*Python 3.8*

Comment: Base64 is just an encoding of the data and does not contain any metadata like filename or extension. But you can figure out what kind of data is encoded in a base64 string by comparing the first few characters as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62329321/how-can-i-check-a-base64-string-is-a-filewhat-type-or-not/62330081#62330081)

Comment: File extension is usually not contained in file data. Do you want to guess the **type** (or data format) of the file?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check type of files without extensions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10937350/how-to-check-type-of-files-without-extensions)

Comment: I need the type of file, but i dont have the file. Just the base64.

Comment: Thanks @jps. Thats it. I think that aswer can be a library in future.