# How to convert base64 data to image

Tags: angular, image, base64, decode, mime-types

I'm trying to display base64 data from the server on my page, I tried first with the code below which works fine with mime type png, I need to cover all image extensions now and I don't know which approach I need to add.
I tried to write a method that extracts the image extension from base64 but when I save the data I don't see anything understandable.

```
private loadArticle(){
    this.facadeArticleService.getArticle().subscribe((storesArticle) => {
      if (storesArticle) {
        this.article = new Article(storesArticle);
        this.updateLogoSource(this.article?.technicalSheet?.logo);
      }
    });
  }

 private updateLogoSource(base64Image: string | undefined) {
    if (base64Image) {
      const imageFormat = this.extractImageFormat(base64Image);
      this.logoSrc = `data:image/${imageFormat};base64,${base64Image}`;
    }
  }

  private extractImageFormat(base64: string): string {
    const formatMatch = base64.substring("data:image/".length, base64.indexOf(";base64"))
    console.log(formatMatch) // iVBORw0KGgo
    return formatMatch ? formatMatch[1] : 'png';
  }
```

Comment: In `extractImageFormat` you seem to expect a string in the format `data:image/png;base64,<actual base64data>`. This format is a [data URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URLs), which contains Base64 data. But actually, as seen in the comment here: `console.log(formatMatch) // iVBORw0KGgo` you get just pure Base64 data, not a data url. That's why your function doesn't work.

Comment: But even if you actually would have a data url, the function `updateLogoSource()` would make no sense, because then you would extract the type from a data url by calling `extractImageFormat()` and create a new data url with the extracted type and append the existing data url to the new one (see this line: `this.logoSrc = `data:image/${imageFormat};base64,${base64Image}`;`).

Comment: If you have in fact just base64 encoded images, not data urls, then you can usually detect the image type by looking at the first few characters of the base64 string. `iVBOR` is the beginnig of a PNG image, `/9j/...` is jpg, and so on. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62329321/how-can-i-check-a-base64-string-is-a-filewhat-type-or-not)