# How to determine image format from Base64 encoded string without prefix?

Tags: javascript, image, base64, data-uri

I received a base64 encoded string of an image from a friend, but the string doesn't include the standard prefix (e.g., "data:image/png;base64," "data:image/jpeg;base64," etc.) to indicate the image format. Without this prefix, I'm unable to determine the image format (JPEG, PNG, WebP, etc.).

Can I somehow determine and display the image format at runtime without knowing the exact image format beforehand? I've tried appending different prefixes (e.g., "data:image/png;base64,") to the base64 encoded string and displaying it as an image, but it didn't work consistently. For example, when the image is encoded in the WebP format but I tried displaying it as PNG, it didn't show up on the website.

Is there a reliable way to determine the image format from a base64 encoded string without the prefix and display it accordingly? I need a solution that works dynamically at runtime. Any suggestions or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Assuming there is no "type clue" encoded in the string (did you try decoding the string and looking?) - you can figure out what type of image by the binary header in the file.  See [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18299806/how-to-check-file-mime-type-with-javascript-before-upload/29672957) and [an implementation that detects more file types](https://gist.github.com/GiantZOC/db1d30b31ffb9d8ca73b6c4f4fe991df)

Comment: Almost every image format has a header that leads to a recognizable character-sequence in Base64, e.g. `iVBOR` for PNG. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62329321/how-can-i-check-a-base64-string-is-a-filewhat-type-or-not/62330081#62330081