If I have a base64 string and I don't know if it is jpg or png or pdf or whatever, how do I convert it to a valid file?
I am trying to get Email attachment from Dynamics CRM and want to save the file in its original format.
When I try to get information from CRM Email entity I am getting a base64 string as the content of the attachment.  I don't know if it is jpg or png or pdf or txt or any other file format, now how can I convert it to its original file format.
Can we identify the format of the file from base64 string itself or we need to have other information to know the file type ??
I tried getting the the 'activitymimeattachments' entity from CRM through postman and I am getting base64 string. Now I want to save whatever this attachment is in its original file format. How can I do that maybe using ADF or Logic Apps

Why don't you just base64-decode the string?  Then it's easy.  Regardless of what it is, that's the operation you need to "convert it to a valid file".

You can recognize many file types by the first few characters of their Base64 representation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62329321/how-can-i-check-a-base64-string-is-a-filewhat-type-or-not

JPG, PNG, and PDF files always start with unique signatures (magic numbers):

JPG files start with bytes FF D8 FF (string ÿØÿ)
PNG files start with bytes 89 50 4E 47 0D 0A 1A 0A (string ‰PNG♪◙→◙)
PDF files start with bytes 25 50 44 46 (string %PDF)

In base64 encoding, each 3 bytes of source data are represented as 4 characters. It means that decoding first 4 characters of base64-encoded data give you first 3 bytes of the source data; decoding first 8 characters of base64-encoded data give you first 6 bytes of the source data, and so on.
To cut the story short,

Base64-encoded JPG files will always start with /9j/
Base64-encoded PNG files will always start with iVBORw0K
Base64-encoded PDF files will always start with JVBE

That would be the quickest and the dirtiest way of identifying the format of the file from base64-encoded string without decoding the string.
By no means this is a sure way of getting the format correct: normal TXT files can also start with %PDF 
Setting that aside, you should be able to get not only the base64-encoded content of the attachment from CRM, but the filename as well! I would suggest you digging in this direction rather than trying to guess the type of the file from its content.
As for decoding the base64-encoded data, you can do it both in the Logic Apps and in the Data Factory.
E.g. see conversion functions for Logic Apps: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#conversion-functions

You can parse the FileName property to get the extension.
Checking the MimeType can also help.

A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.

To elaborate what @Aron is saying you can query the activitymimeattachment entity, return the fields for filename & mimetype and get the information from there. Here's an example using C# and the Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk:
private Entity[] GetAttachments(IOrganizationService service, ITracingService log, EntityReference Email)
    {
        // Define Condition Values
        var query_objectid = Email.Id;

        // Instantiate QueryExpression query
        var query = new QueryExpression("activitymimeattachment");

        // Add columns to query.ColumnSet
        query.ColumnSet.AddColumns("objectid", "filename", "mimetype", "attachmentid", "body", "attachmentnumber", "subject");

        // Define filter query.Criteria
        query.Criteria.AddCondition("objectid", ConditionOperator.Equal, query_objectid);

        log.Trace($"Querying for attachments for Email {Email.Id} {Email.Name}");
        return service.RetrieveMultiple(query).Entities.ToArray();
    }

Then you can iterate through the attachments and set the values you need. Note that email being passed in the GetAttachments method is an entity reference defined before.
var attachments = GetAttachments(service, log, email);

        log.Trace("Found {0} attachments.", attachments.Length);

        foreach (var attachement in attachments)
        {                
            var filename = attachement.GetAttributeValue<string>("filename");
            
            var mimetype = attachement.GetAttributeValue<string>("mimetype");
            
            var subject = attachement.GetAttributeValue<string>("subject");
            
            
            log.Trace($"FileName: {fileName}, Subject: {subject} MimeType: {mimeType}");
            
        }

If you want to get the file ext, you can do something like this:
var fileExt = fileName.Substring(fileName.LastIndexOf('.'));

or
string extension = Path.GetExtension(fileName);

The above code can work in an Azure function and if you want you can add your Azure Function to a Logic App.
The above could also be used as in a Plugin or Custom Workflow Activity.
Hope this helps :)
